# Similar approaches to taking user input showing completely different output

Tags: c, variables, input, sum, user-input

As a beginner, I was trying different approaches to code in C(vs code) to learn better. 1st approach went well, but in 2nd approach I got the different output than what i was expected. I was coding to get the sum of two digits. So in 1st approach I got the sum of two digits as output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   int first_number, second_number;

   printf("Enter First Number: ");
   scanf("%i", &first_number);

   printf("Enter Second Number: ");
   scanf("%i", &second_number);

   int sum = first_number + second_number;
   printf("Your Sum is %i.", sum);
}
```

But in 2nd approach, instead of getting sum of two digits in output I got number of two digits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("Enter First Number: ");
   int first_number = scanf("%i", &first_number);

   printf("Enter Second Number: ");
   int second_number = scanf("%i", &second_number);

   int sum = first_number + second_number;
   printf("Your Sum is %i.", sum);
```

Please tell why is it happening?
Thank you in advance for answering my question. Have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf()` function returns the number of fields(variables) that were successfully converted and assigned. In your case it's one for each. So `1` is assigned to `first_number` and `second_number`, and the sum of both is `2`. Remember that `first_number` and `second_number` are modified before `scanf` has returned, so both of these values will be overridden by the `scanf` return values, which are `1` in your case.

**Let's visualize what is happening:**

**Input**

```
5
10
```

**What Is Happening**

```
// when scanf is still running 
first_number = 5;
// after scanf has completed
first_number = 1;

// when scanf is still running 
second_number = 10;
// after scanf has completed
second_number = 1;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it completely. Can you please elaborate a bit more why it didn't happen in the first case via comparing both block of codes. Or you can point to that particular line of code that went wrong.

Comment: In the first case you were only modifying ```first_number``` and ```second_number``` while in the second case you were modifying and assigning the return value of ```scanf``` to ```first_number``` and ```second_number```.